# Falling space debris defence systems in the Star wars universe

Tags: star-wars

I was recently watching Episode 3 and a few clone wars episodes, and I found myself thinking during the opening battle between the Republic and General Grievous' forces above Coruscant, on a planet so densely populated where potentially thousands of inhabitants can be killed from a drifting capital class ship with a decaying orbit during space battles what defenses are in place?

Is there any instances of some form of emergency services that tractor beam chunks of debris to safe landing places or repulsor towers that can slow or suspend it until it can be taken apart safely? Even disintegration lasers or emergency force field generators like the types deployed on Hoth as they must have the energy output capable of sustaining it. This IS the galactic capital so must have some advanced tech at its deposal. Even now in our own development humans have certain preventative measures for all types of threats and ways of tracking them, plus responses or fall back plans.

Comment: Coruscant has a top-notch planetary shield (actually a pair of concentric ones), but this could be a concern on other worlds.

Comment: we have fallback plans? you mean, we are not all going to die when a major meteorite hits Earth?

Comment: Well I would assume there are "best/worst case scenarios" and bunkers for meteors at our current tech level lol. How far out would the planetary shields work? As Anakin and Kenobi were on a chunk that was in reentry as they escaped.

Comment: @flq: The difference between us and catastrophic meteors vs Coruscant and falling debris are: catastrophic meteor strikes are much, much rarer on Earth than falling cruisers in Star Wars; and the technological feasibility gap is much lower in the latter case. And even still, NASA scientists and other researchers around the globe are pushing for a meteor defense system.

Comment: Im sure they do, we just didn't see it.

Comment: The main difference between a capital ship and a meteor is that a ship is mainly empty space, with a bit of tinfoil around it (from a planet's point of view), while a meteorite is solid. Unprotected by shields, a ship will burn up more or less completely in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also assume that the reentry level and angle will play a factor; coming straight in would undoubtedly break apart a ship and burn up much of the smaller debris.

It's a good question and theory, BadMike; we get airplane crashes from malfunctions at least once a year, and you would think that a starship would have the same instances. I would assume that a planet such as Coruscant would have a system in place, much like how star ships have barriers to prevent air from escaping breaches in the hull and the opening of docks for ingress/egress of shuttles and smaller ships. A planetary-sized shield, I would think, would be much to massive and too expensive, but perhaps there is an orbiting ring of satallites that would help prevent it, if there were a mayday.

I would assume that since there is an ongoing battle above the skies of Coruscant, that any emergency system is either overworked, or targeted first by the Imperial forces. So if a ship went down and got sucked into the planet's gravity well, it no becomes a factor of math, physics, and blind old luck. I'd imagine that that flagship that Anikin and Obi-wan re-entered with probably scattered debris over a wide swath of city, though anything smaller than say a room was probably scorched to ashes and anything larger probably broke up and became less of a nuiscence.

I would assume that since that was more or less Coruscant's Battle of London, I would suspect that a good chunk of the population is either bunkered or shielded (like neighborhoods with a barrier on top) for such an eventuality, since I would think that the threat of a planetary bombardment would have the Republic thinking of its citizenry.

While there isn't a real canocal answer set up, I'm resorting to logic and history. A planetary system would be too much, but I could see area barriers being erected for the possibility of a burn-in.