# How do planets prevent a Gravity-type event?

Tags: star-wars

Lots of things blow up near planets in Star Wars (Coruscant in Episode III being an obvious example). Why doesn't this end up more like the movie *Gravity*?

Comment: I imagine between particle shields for protection and tractor beams for cleanup, space junk is not too hard to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, they do have both of those things.

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39449/5137. The existing answer isn’t great, and I’m sure someone could do better.

Comment: For future reference, it's called Kessler Syndrome

Answer (score 1):

In *Star Wars*, *Millennium Falcon* emerged from hyperspace in the middle of the shattered remains of an entire planet, Alderaan, which the Death Star had just obliterated.  Other than a few bumps similar to turbulence on an airliner, the *Falcon's* passengers were unmussed.  So while orbits may well be full of debris, the standard shield technology is good enough that no one has to worry about it.

Comment: Yes, but how do *planets* deal with this? Also, probably it would be best to put this answer on the duplicate question....

Comment: Debris of small size would vaporize in the atmosphere anyways. Larger debris - unless explicitly brought on a crash trajectory - is not that frequent and can be cleaned up. Especially when you've got technology like shields, tractor beams and blasters and can get ships into orbit with little effort.